# Rstudio Resizing off when I using Monitor

Tags: r, resize, rstudio, autoresize

Hi so I downloaded R and Rstudio for the first time. When I code, I like to use a seperate monitor, but when I dragged RStudio to the monitor, the toolbar shrunk, a black band appears at the top of my screen, and my mouse clicks are off (like to click on something, my mouse had to be above the button instead of on it). This never happened before when I used other IDEs on my monitor. Here are some screenshots! I would appreciate if someone could let me know why RStudio is acting like this. Thanks!

Before (Main Screen):
[image: Before (Main Screen)]

After (Monitor):
[image: After (Monitor)]

Comment: Fascinating issue. I've used dozens of multi-monitor setups with Rstudio and never had an issue - it may be a problem with your graphics settings or there may be something else causing the problem. Either way, please provide more details (such as your OS, monitor configuration, SessionInfo() output, etc)

Comment: I'm currently using R studio in three different multi-monitor setups and have not run into any similar issues. I take that for you this problem is limited to R studio and not other software as well?

Comment: Face value, it looks like a difference in the display resolution of your screens. Have you tried looking at your system settings? Or, when you move any program from one screen to another, does it automatically resize? Other than that, have you tried zooming in?
Check the settings: Tools > Global Options > Appearance > Zoom.
Or press: `Ctrl`+`+`.

Comment: Hi, here's a bit more information. My OS is windows 10. This problem is limited to rstudio and not any other software like anaconda, pycharms, etc.

Comment: @chrimaho I have tried using `Ctrl`+`+` and other Appearance settings, but it doesn't seem to affect the taskbar display and the clicking problem.